# Make the img tag width and height 100% inside overflow hidden div while maintaining the aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I need to make the img tag width and height 100% inside overflow hidden div while maintaining the aspect ratio.

What I reached for is putting the image within overflow hidden div And the image is max-width 100% and auto height.

```
<div id="foo">
    <img src="http://www.engineering.com/Portals/0/BlogFiles/swertel/heart-cloud.jpg" />
</div>
```

but the problem i'm facing is not go height 100%

[image]

**Look the code in action http://fiddle.jshell.net/TARwL/**

And get close look at the div#cover is 100% width and height is perfect look and i would like to see my code do the same

I can't use the background-size:cover method because ***beside*** is not working in older browsers, **I can't click right and save the image and this is important to me**

Comment: Your problem is set on the fact that you are using and img tag and not a background to do this. If you simply assign the img a height of 100%, you will see that you get what you want, but the image is not centered. This happens because you are using a existent element and not using the image as an attribute of the parent div. So, the only way you can get this done is by cropping the image to a square format or by background-size.

Comment: @GEspinha - you can do this without background images  see my answer

Comment: @Danield If the image is dynamically generated and has a different size you can't check the margin-left negative size.

Comment: @Jim: Why can't you save a bckground image? In all major browsers right clicking on the image opens the context menu with the option to show the background image and then you can easily save it. But beside of this question - did I get you right, that the image should fill the entire DIV (square) and maintain its aspect ratio (which in your example means that some parts of the left and right side will overflow and ar not visible)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I rethought and I found eligible solution for me, I don't know if will suit anyone else !!

The Image will be background size cover and at the same time I will add the image inside the same div with 100% width and height and 0 opacity

So the image will show like cover and anyone can click on the same area and use the image like normal (copy link, download, etc.)

HTML

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://www.engineering.com/Portals/0/BlogFiles/swertel/heart-cloud.jpg)">
    <img src="http://www.engineering.com/Portals/0/BlogFiles/swertel/heart-cloud.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
 div{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:50% 50%;
    }

    div img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        /* OLD IE */
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    }
```

Code In Action http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/mVtJc/1/

Comment: I actually prefer your answer over mine. very nice.

Comment: You pretty creative. Me like this

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to use a Script for this one. (unless you want to use a centered background image)

[**Working Fidlle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/TARwL/9/)
[try it with any image you want, with different aspects ratios]

**JQuery**

```
var img = $("#foo > img");
var ratio = img.width() / img.height();
var limit = (100*ratio)+"%";
var margin = ((1-ratio)*50)+"%";

if( ratio > 1)
{
    img.css({"width": limit, "margin-left": margin});
}
else
{
    ratio = 1 / ratio;
    img.css({"height": limit, "margin-top": margin});
}
```

**Edit:**

this [**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/TARwL/12/) support multiple images at once (use the `foo` class)

Comment: I tested on a larger image with different aspect http://fiddle.jshell.net/TARwL/10/

Comment: that because you can't have 2 elements with the same id in the page.. try the new fiddle in my solution..

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (**Note** this will only work if you use images with the same aspect ratios)

```
#foo img {
    width:133.33%;
    margin-left: -16.66%; /* crop img to the left: 33.33 /2 = 16.66 */
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/TARwL/8/)**

### Explanation:

Your image is 1024px wide X 768px high. So width to height ratio= 1.333.

However your `overflow:hidden` div has a raio 1X1 - so the image will be distorted at 100%.

So in order to display the image to ratio - you need to increase the width by 133%.

Then, in order to center or 'crop' the image to fit the div - use margin.

Comment: You can only dynamically determine the margin-left size with javascript, so the image is going to have some positioning issues if it has a different size.

Comment: @GEspinha the OP didn't say that it had to work for all image sizes - for all I know - he just needed a solution for that particular image

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I'm just assuming the percentage can come out of that idea, to use hard coding 'margin-left' values, then it would be easier to use a square sized image and still rely on pure CSS.

Comment: @GEspinha - I updated my answer using a percentage margin and added note that it will only work for images with that same aspect ratio

Comment: I know that, that's exactly what i said :) "and added note that it will **only** work for images with that same aspect ratio"

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do this trick on images with different sizes on divs with different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Another proposal: [**jsFiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/H8KXy/1/)

I really did not understand why it shouldn't be possible to use a background-iamge!?
So you can use the example code as long as the width and height of the containing div remains the same and also the aspect ration of the image stays at 4:3.

If any of the values changes you have to adapt at least the value for `left` (the calculation can easily be done with Javascript).

Not using a background-image make the whole thing very "fragile" ..., and from a semantically point of view it is also "not ideal".

Would be better to use a server side technique to crop the image to the desired/ needed size.

Comment: I can't use background-image because need to be allowed to download the image, when the image background you can't copy or download the images

Comment: @Jim: That's not true - see my comment on your original question. ;-) Would be even better to use Javascript to offer the image for download when being clicked, rather than to use non-semantically markup.

Comment: only firefox :(, I tested chrome and opera and safari and they all not offer the image, i will look for a server side solution, any suggestion?

Comment: @Jim: Yes, you are right ... (comes from usually using FF) ;-). There is a good tutorial on [**nettuts+**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/). The most common library for this is the **GD Library**. You'll find hundreds of tutorials when searching for it. What I still didn't understand about your question is, which parts are dynamically - means the width and height of what elements may change? And can you ensure that all images inquestion at least have the same aspect ratio?

Comment: Nevermind about the server side solution, I did a little trick with pure css, look at it above, and Thank you for your time, I'm really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like:

```
.image-container {
    width: 169px; // May be auto
    height: 169px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    .image-wrap {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out; //Run on IE
        height: 100%; // Height full frame
        img.scale {
            height: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: none !important; // To make sure that width of the image can be larger than its container.
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <div class="image-wrap"><img class="scale" src="your image path" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers it is possible to use the property `object-fit: cover`

```
<style>
    #foo {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #foo img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
</style>

<div id="foo">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/davox/z5a728jm/7/

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Howto/Fill_a_box_with_an_image